# How to convert multiple CSV Files to Shapefiles/Feature Classes using ModelBuilder

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, modelbuilder, csv, error-000210

I am trying to convert multiple csv files into separate shapefiles using ModelBuilder in ArcMap 10.5. I have generated the following model:[image]

In this model I am, specifying a folder containing multiple csv files. I then use an 'Iterate Tables' iterator to go through all the csv files in that folder. Then the 'Copy Rows' tool is used to write the rows from the input csv table to a new table in a Geodatabase. I am then using the 'Make XY Event Layer' tool to convert the table into an XY Layer. To make this an actual Feature Class and not just a layer file I use the 'Copy Features' tool.

When I run the model, I get an error message when the model tries to 'Copy Features':

ERROR 000210: Cannot create output C:\Users\jkhangura\Documents\Trial\Shapefile\Test.gdb\MiamiBeach
Failed to execute (Copy Features).

Can someone help me understand where I am failing with this model?

Comment: Can you confirm that the make xy layer tool executed as expected? Try adding to display.  If that is not what you expected then it would suggest the source failed to copy correctly.

Comment: Try using Feature Class to Feature Class instead of Copy Features

Comment: Does `C:\Users\jkhangura\Documents\Trial\Shapefile\Test.gdb\MiamiBeach` already exist?  Do you see this error on the first or a subsequent iteration?  What additional messaging shows in the Results window?